# Error on http does not exist on component fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am getting an error that states property http does not exist on quizlistcomponent. I dont know why this error is occuring as this code is for an assignment and came right out of the book.

````
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "quiz-list",
  templateUrl: './quiz-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-list.component.css']
})

export class QuizListComponent {
  title: string;
  selectedQuiz: Quiz;
  quizzes: Quiz[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.title = "Latest Quizzes";
    var url = baseUrl + "api/quiz/Latest/";

    this.http.get<Quiz[]>(url).subscribe(result => {
      this.quizzes = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  onSelect(quiz: Quiz) {
    this.selectedQuiz = quiz;
    console.log("quiz with Id "
      + this.selectedQuiz.Id
      + " has been selected.");
  }
}```

The error is occuring on the ```this.http``` call
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an access modifier to the parameter so it knows to transmute it into a property on the object and not just expect an argument.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient ...
```